# Exception converting xls file to tab-delimited file

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have couple of ".xls" files on a folder and need to convert it into tab seperated values
Found a vb script for this ..please some body sugest how to do this?
I am getting couple of error when running this.I am not a vb programmer.Experts...please help

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim WScript As Object = Nothing   '' with out nothing it was showing an error
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object

   If WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
      WScript.Echo("Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv")
      Wscript.Quit()
   End If
   oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))  ''item o might be excel
   oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\5A5.xls")
   oBook.SaveAs(WScript.Arguments.Item(1), -4158)

   oBook.Close(False)
   oExcel.Quit()
   WScript.Echo("Done")

End Sub
```

The exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:    
   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
     ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set.
```

Comment: You could have at least shown these "errors"... :P

Comment: Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying to use `WScript` but it has not been initialized (it's set to Nothing).

Try it without it:

```
   Dim oExcel As Object
   Dim oBook As Object

   oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\5A5.xls")
   oBook.SaveAs("C:\Users\5A5.txt", -4158)

   oBook.Close(False)
   oExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks a loooooot for the help